# Pasting HTML into mongo is breaking all my queries

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm pasting in this specific html into a field in mongo, where I place all sorts of other html just fine, but when I paste this in and save it - ALL my Mongo queries break and I have to readd the data to my collection to bring it back:

This was a pain to figure out - there's gotta be a wierd character, but how can I prevent this?

All i'm doing to send the data to mongo is this in angular
Restangular.one('/api/update').customPUT(data); and this in node Things.findOneAndUpdate({_id: o._id}, o, {upsert: true})

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="form-group">

    <label style="font-weight: bold" class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inp_{{schemaId}}">{{schema[_Label]}} <span class="txt-color-red" ng-show="schema[_Required]" title="{{schema[_Label]}} is required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input">
            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            <input type="email" id="inp_{{schema._id}}" ng-model="data[schema._id]" placeholder="Enter {{schema[_Label]}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="note" ng-show="schema[_HelpText]">{{schema[_HelpText]}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If I paste this into SublimeText, then paste it back into the field, it works fine.    How can I enforce conversion to an acceptable mongo format?

Answer (score 0):

If you store HTML as a JSON object, it would be wise to escape all the special characters before sending it to Mongo:

```
& : &amp
< : &lt
> : &gt
" : &quot
' : &#39
/ : &#x2F
```

This way, you'll have pure string and it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the HTML fragment using Base64 algorithm.

Encode before inserting:

```
encodedHTML = new Buffer(html).toString('base64'));
```

And decode after retrieving:

```
new Buffer(encodedHTML, 'base64').toString('ascii')
```

With this, you'll avoid errors with special characters.